# JButton error cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm working on a simple Java GUI, but an error came out about the method `addActionListener` of the `JButton` when I applied it. Here are my codes. The error is marked with `ERROR`.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class KiloConverter extends JFrame {

    private JPanel panel;                   //To reference a panel
    private JLabel messageLabel;            //To reference a label
    private JTextField kiloTextField;       //To reference a text field
    private JButton calcButton;             //To reference a button
    private final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 310;   //Window width
    private final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 100;  //Window height

    public KiloConverter() {

        setTitle("Kilometer Converter");        //Set the window title
        setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);    //Set the size of the window

        //Specify what happens when the close button is clicked
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        buildPanel();                           //Build panel and add to frame
        add(panel);                             //Add panel to content pane
        setVisible(true);                       //Display the window
    }

    private void buildPanel() {

        messageLabel = new JLabel("Enter a distance in kilometers");
        kiloTextField = new JTextField(10);
        calcButton = new JButton("Calculate");

        //ERROR - method addActionListener in class AbstractButton cannot be   
        //applied to given types
        //reason: actual argument KiloConverter.CalcButtonListener cannot be 
        //converted to ActionListener by method invocation conversion.
        calcButton.addActionListener(new CalcButtonListener()); 



        panel = new JPanel();

        panel.add(messageLabel);
        panel.add(kiloTextField);
        panel.add(calcButton);
    }

    private class CalcButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String input;
            double miles;

            input = kiloTextField.getText();
            miles = Double.parseDouble(input) * 0.6214;

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, input + "kilometers is " +
                    miles + " miles.");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new KiloConverter();
    }
}
```

The interface class:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public interface ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e);
}
```

Comment: Have you re-implemented the `ActionListener` interface?  `JButton` is expecting an instance of `java.awt.ActionListener`

Comment: `private final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 310;`  Don't set the size of top level containers.  Instead layout the content & call `pack()`.

Comment: What do you mean by re-implemented the ActionListener interface?
@AndrewThompson Oh alright, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Tip: Add @MadProgrammer (or whoever) to notify them of a new comment.  Of course, only one person can be notified per comment.  Comments should be separated on that basis.

Comment: Ahhh okay, I'm fairly new to this website. Gotta learn the syntax lol

Comment: @MadProgrammer What do you mean by re-implemented the ActionListener Interface?

Comment: What I mean is, there is a `interface` called `ActionListener` in `java.awt.*`.  Did you create your own (and call it `ActionListener`)?

Comment: Yeah, I created my own and called it `ActionListener`. I think that might be the problem

Comment: @MadProgrammer Wow, that fixed everything! Thanks!! Do you want to submit an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1):

From the sound of your comments, you've created your own `interface` called `ActionListener`.

`JButton` requires an instance of `java.awt.ActionListener`.

Try removing your implementation and implement `java.awt.ActionListener` within your own listeners.